# How to regex the beginning and the end of a sentence - python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings containing dates, country, and city:

```
myList = ["(1922, May, 22; USA; CHICAGO)","(1934, June, 15; USA; BOSTON)"]
```

I want to extract only the date and the city (cities are always with capital letters).
So far I have this:

```
for info in myList:

        pattern_i = re.compile(r"[^;]+")
        pattern_f = re.compile(r";\s\b([A-Z]+)\)")

        mi = re.match(pattern_i, info)
        mf = re.match(pattern_f, info)

        print(mi)
        print(mf)
```

I am getting:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='(1922, May, 22'>
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='(1934, June, 15'>
None
```

I've tried so many things and can't seem to find a solution. What am I missing here?

Comment: I would suggest simply split on `;` and take the first and last element

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, my issue is why I am getting None for mf.

Comment: @CodeManiac now I don't understand how I didn't think of this before. It does the job, thanks! But I am still curious, why am I getting None for mf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> thanks! But I am still curious, why am I getting None for mf?
> ```
>
> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default). [`Ref DOcs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

---

`re.match` searches for match at the beginning of string, since the pattern you're trying to match isn't at the start of string so you're getting `None` you can use `re.search` is one option to find match value anywhere in the string

---

As i suggested split is a better option here, you should split by `;` and take the first and last element to get the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Regex is overkill for data with simple, consistent formatting.
This can be done easily using the built in string manipulation functions.

```py
for entry in myList:
    date, country, city = [x.strip() for x in entry[1:-1].split(';')]

# Explanation
entry[1:-1] # Strip off the parenthesis
entry[1:-1].split(';') # Split into a list of strings using the ';' character
x.strip() # Strip extra whitespace
```

Comment: True, this is much better than a regex.

Comment: Overkill indeed, my bad. I was so absorbed with regex for other stuff that I completely forgot about `split` for this task.

Answer (score 0):

regex for date: `^\(([^;]+)`

regex for city `([A-Z]+)\)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`:

```
p='\((?P<date>.*);.*;(?P<city>.*)\)'

pd.Series(myList).str.extract(p)
```

Output:

```
             date      city
0   1922, May, 22   CHICAGO
1  1934, June, 15    BOSTON
```